# Remove space between navbar and jumbotron in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

There is space between my navbar and the jumbotron in bootstrap 3. There is also space between  the jumbotron and 3 horizontal thumbnails. I want to get rid of this space. Do I have to change the CSS and change the padding or what is the best way?

**_Header**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div style="font-family:Webdings;">
      <%= link_to "Project", root_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Team", team_path %></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Resources<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link_to "Action 1", about_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Action 2", about_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Action 3", about_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Action 4", about_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", register_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav
```

**Home (with thumbnails)**

```
<%= provide(:title, "Home") %>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Welcome to club!</h1>
    <p>blabla</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign Up</a></p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="column">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://b2bleadblog.com/images/2007/05/18/huddlehands.jpg" alt="My Image" />
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Blablabla</h3>
        <p style="font-size:17px">Blablalbal.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 22):

You have to set `margin-bottom:0;` to `navbar` and `jumbotron` classes. You can use a custom stylesheet to override this. Use custom CSS next to the bootstrap css reference. as below:

```
  <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <link href="../css/CustomStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**See this [bootply](http://bootply.com/77244) example**

Answer (score -1):

A way to remove space between jumbotron and navbar is to change your line:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
```

Into:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

Answer (score -5):

Sometimes the problem is the extra space in the HTML, try:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    ...
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign Up</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    ...
</div>
```

Note that I removed two `\n` between divs.

Comment: Hey sorry where do you see these "\n"?

Comment: I meant two empty lines (spaces, "enter", "return").

Comment: @cortex, No. spaces, return or hard enters will not give any extra lines or spaces in HTML. Please be aware of this. See my answer below.